# Using R to Compare Dates

Tags: r, date, csv

I've got two csv files.

One file lists when and why an employee leaves.

```
EmployeeID,Department,Separation_Type,Separation_Date,FYFQ    
119549,Sales,Retirement,09/30/2013  
2629053,Sales,Termination,09/30/2013  
120395,Sales,Retirement,11/01/2013  
122450,Sales,Transfer,11/30/2013  
123962,Sales,Transfer,11/30/2013  
1041054,Sales,Resignation,12/01/2013  
990962,Sales,Retirement,12/14/2013  
135396,Sales,Retirement,01/11/2014
```

Another file is a lookup table shows the start and end dates of every fiscal quarter:

```
FYFQ,Start,End  
FY2014FQ1,10/1/2013,12/31/2013   
FY2014FQ2,1/1/2014,3/31/2014  
FY2014FQ3,4/1/2014,6/30/2014  
FY2014FQ4,7/1/2014,9/30/2014  
FY2015FQ1,10/1/2014,12/31/2014  
FY2015FQ2,1/1/2015,3/31/2015
```

I'd like R to find what FYFQ the Separation_Date occurred in and print it into a fourth column in the data.

**Input:**

```
Separations.csv:   
>EmployeeID,Department,Separation_Type,Separation_Date,FYFQ       
>990962,Sales,Retirement,12/14/2013  
>135396,Sales,Retirement,01/11/2014
```

FiscalQuarterDates.csv:

```
>FYFQ,Start,End  
>FY2013FQ4,7/1/2013,9/30/2013   
>FY2014FQ1,10/1/2013,12/31/2013  
>FY2014FQ2,1/1/2014,3/31/2014
```

**Desired Output:**
Output.csv:

```
>EmployeeID,Department,Separation_Type,Separation_Date,FYFQ      
>990962,Sales,Retirement,12/14/2013,FY2014FQ1
>135396,Sales,Retirement,01/11/2014,FY2014FQ2
```

I'm assuming there's some function that would iterate through the FiscalQuarterDates.csv and evaluate if each separation date was in a FYFQ, but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

**This is what worked.**

```
#read in csv and declare th3 4th column a date
separations <- read.csv(file="Separations_DummyData.csv", head=TRUE,sep=",",colClasses=c(NA,NA,NA,"Date"))


#Use the zoo package (I installed it) to convert separation_date to quarter type and then set the quarter back by 1/4. Then construct the variable with FYyFQq. 
library(zoo)
separations$FYFQ <- format(as.yearqtr(separations$Separation_Date, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1/4, "FY%YFQ%q")

#Write out this to CSV in working directory.
write.csv(separations, file = "sepscomplete.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

You really don't need a second dataframe: A simple function will solve this:

```
yr<-with(firstdf,as.numeric(substr(Seperation_Date,7,10)))
mth<-with(firstdf,as.numeric(substr(Seperation_Date,1,2)))


    firstdf$FYFQ<-with(firstdf,
ifelse(mth<=3,paste0("FY",yr,"FQ2"),
ifelse(mth>3 & mth<=6,paste0("FY",yr,"FQ3"),
ifelse(mth>7 & mth<=9,paste0("FY",yr,"FQ4"),
paste0("FY",yr+1,"FQ1")
))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert each date to `"yearqtr"` class (from the zoo package) and add 1/4 to shift it to the next calendar quarter.  Then write it out using `write.csv`:

```
library(zoo)
DF$FYFQ <- format(as.yearqtr(DF$Separation_Date, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1/4, "FY%YFQ%q")
```

giving:

```
> write.csv(DF, file = stdout(), row.names = FALSE)
"EmployeeID","Department","Separation_Type","Separation_Date","FYFQ"
990962,"Sales","Retirement","12/14/2013","FY2014FQ1"
135396,"Sales","Retirement","01/11/2014","FY2014FQ2"
```

**Note:**

**1)** If `FYFQ` need not be exactly in the format shown then it could be simplified to just:

```
DF$FYFQ <- as.yearqtr(DF$Separation_Date, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1/4
```

**2)** The second input file listed in the question is not used.

**3)**  We used this for the input data:

```
Lines <- "EmployeeID,Department,Separation_Type,Separation_Date,FYFQ  
990962,Sales,Retirement,12/14/2013
135396,Sales,Retirement,01/11/2014"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

**4)** Fixed so that it produces shifted calendar quarters.

Answer (score 0):

The text of this answer was just a copy of another answer so it has been moved to the question.

Comment: Its not necessary to repeat another answer.  Everyone will know which answer you used by which one you check off.  Use comments or update your question if you wish to provide additional feedback.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck "what worked" wasn't just one answer so I made the comment.